# loading html into a DIV by class selector using javascript and or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have a `div` element as below in my html:

```
<div class="tile-group six">
```

I am looking to use this javascript somehow to load html into the `div` above

```
<script>          
 $(".tile").click(function(e) {
    $(".tile").toggleClass("flipOutX"); 
   $("tile-group six").load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");
 });    
</script>
```

It is the second part of the function (the first part does some effect that is currently working so added the line below with the .load bit).

This works for a `div` id but not for a class. Is this possible?

I NOW HAVE IT WORKING BUT IT HAPPENS TOOO QUICKLY SO I HAVE BEEN ADVISED THE FOLLOWING....

```
$(".tile").click(function(e) {
  $(".tile").toggleClass("flipOutX").promise().done(function(){
    $(".tile-group .six").load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");
});
```

But that does nothing and wont let the function run.???

THE CSS for the flipOutX function

```
@-webkit-keyframes flipOutX {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px);
    transform: perspective(400px);
  }

  30% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes flipOutX {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px);
    transform: perspective(400px);
  }

  30% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.flipOutX {
  -webkit-animation-name: flipOutX;
  animation-name: flipOutX;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
  backface-visibility: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: The selectors  $("tile-group six") looks up _elements_ called <tile-group> and <six>... use a dot before the names to look up classes:  $(".tile-group .six")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are missing class selector. Change

```
$("tile-group six").load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");
```

to

```
$(".tile-group .six").load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to perform the `load` action when the `toggleClass` is completed, you can use promises:

```
$(".tile").toggleClass("flipOutX").promise().done(function(){
    $(".tile-group .six").load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");
});
```

Comment: That worked but interfered with the first part of the function which takes about 2seconds to complete... is there any way to add a delay to the load to let the flipOutX bit finish up ?

Comment: i need to see the first part of the function to see what you exactly are doing.

Comment: it is the first line of the function i originially posted .....   $(".tile").toggleClass("flipOutX");    ...... it cause a number of tiles within the class "tile-group six" to perform a css transition... takes roughly 2 seconds

Comment: How about `$(".tile").toggleClass("flipOutX").done(function() {$(".tile-group .six").load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");});`

Comment: @user3504751 check out my update in the answer. As @mark partially mentioned, you can use `.promise().done()` to accomplish this.

Comment: just having a spot of bother on implementing .. nothing working was the "How about $(".title").... as a complete replacement or an addition repeated from the first line ?

Comment: check my UPDATE on my answer, you will see the full implementation.

Comment: used your pointer of .promise().done() but now nothing happens ... hmm..... any ideas ?

Comment: here check out this fiddle, it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/uvck4mcz/. Note that I changed the `.load()` because I do no have access to your html file.

Comment: Just ripped the code straight into my project and adjusted text for .load and the url in text replacement.... still no joy .... hmmm ?

Comment: Do you see any error in your console? I can't really suggest anything further without seeing your whole code. As you can see, it is working on the demo.

Comment: ok that worked once i changed the #trigger to .tile ..... but it still doesn't wait for the first part of the function to complete , very strange

Comment: first part of the function appears to be only toggling a class. It should not take too long. What exactly are you doing with toggleClass

Comment: good question, it basically causes the tiles to perform a css flipOutX transition .  There are 8 tiles that flip out over a couple of seconds then I want to dump the html content from the other page into the space the tiles occupy which is called "tile-area six" in this instance.

Comment: not quite , I am not looking to fade I have defined a css webkit transition called flipOutX which changes the shape and size and opacity of the tiles.... is toggleclass causing the problem ? should i consider using a timer between the two functions ?

Comment: can you provide the `flipOutX` css content? Also, yes you can use `.setInterval()` to make it delay as much as you want, but not sure if it would be the best practice.

Comment: just posted the css for flipOutX

Comment: I think the best way might be to use a setTimeout() method into the function , ,what do you think mate ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75419/discussion-between-caner-akdeniz-and-user3504751).

Answer (score 0):

Notice the `.`. It signifies a [class is used as selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/). So if you want to select an element (or many) with the class(es) `tile-group six`:

```
$(".tile-group .six").load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");
```

If you can, it would probably be better practice to use an [id as selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):

```
<div id="myDiv" class="whatever"></div>

$('#myDiv').load();
```

The reason being that you can have many classes named "title-group six" (doesn't have to be unique), and that would load your content into all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Jquery class selector https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

So you can use:

the Jquery selector:
`$( ".myClass .myChildClass" )`

the JavaScript selector like this: `document.getElementsByClassName('myclass').getElementsByClassName('myChildclass')` to find all the 'myChildclass' who have 'myclass' as parent class in your DOM

Answer (score -1):

Can you try

```
$(this).closest("div").load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");
```

Comment: Hi I am just trying the above to see how that goes as it references the specific class